# Printer settings changes when RDP to the terminal server

Tags: printing

I have a network printer mapped on the workstation.
Printer on this workstation is set to print as black&white only.
I RDP to the Terminal Server and printer is getting populated there as well automatically.

Unfortunately, after login to terminal server color preferences are changed back to color for this particular printer.

What should I do to get the same preferences as on the fat client?

I have heard that it has something to to with initial printer settings on the PC where the printer is installed and the advice I got was to uninstall the printer from the server, then from all workstations, install it on the server again, set all settings and map it on all workstations.

I was wondering if there is an easier way to do it.
I will be great for any help.
I will provide more information if needed of course.

Comment: This question will likely get migrated to www.serverfault.com where you will likely get a better answer

Comment: Hi, I was trying to post in there but I was diverted several times and ended up here. I would appreciate if you could move it there.

Greets
Mariusz